# python overwrite parents behavior while keeping parents method and name

Tags: python-3.x

I want to inherit from the parent but overwrite the behavior. I want to keep the behavior of the parent so I can still call it from the overwritten method. The parent function is complicated and comes from a library, which I don't want to reimplement. I want to overwrite because the name is important (for compatibility). Here is some pseudo code that explains what I want.

```py
class Parent:
  def importantName(data):
    print(data)

class Child(Parent):
  def importantName(data):
    data2 = data+" world!"
    return super.importantName(data2) # call parents function
```

```
>>> c = Child()
>>> c.importantName("Hello")
Hello World!
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Things I have thought of but would not work (worst case scenario this is only option):

```py
class Parent:
  def importantName(data):
    print(data)

class Child(Parent):
  def differentName(self,data):
    data2 = data+" world!"
    return self.importantName(data2)
```

```
>>> c = Child()
>>> c.differentName("Hello")
Hello World!
```

In this case it would not work because I have to call `c.differentName()` instead of `c.importantName()`. In this case if I call `c.importantName()` it would call the Parent function and not the overwritten one.

Comment: Since your pseudocode already uses ˋsuperˋ, why don’t you actually use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python has the [`super` builtin](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super), which does exactly what you want. When called, it returns a proxy to the preceding types in the method resolution order - usually, this is the parent class. When used directly in the body of a method, it can be called without parameters.

```
class Parent:
    def importantName(self, data):
        print(data)

class Child(Parent):
    def importantName(self, data):
        data2 = data + " world!"
        return super().importantName(data2) # call parents function
```

Comment: What if there are multimple inheritance?
`class child(paren1, parent2):`

Comment: ``super`` supports multiple inheritance just fine. ``super()`` is a *dynamic* lookup in the Method Resolution Order -- meaning that with multiple inheritance, some other (but well-defined) class than the immediate parent class can be picked first. See [the article linked in the docs](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/) for a discussion and examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can infact do super calls in python. Your initial stab is pretty close.

Here's an example:

```py
class x:  # Some library class
    def foo(self, y):  # Function we want to extend
        ...

class more_x(x):  # subclass of x
    def __init__(self, vars_for, initializing, class_x):  # subclass initializer
        super(more_x, self).__init__(vars_for, initializing, class_x)
        ...  # Additional initialization if required / overrides of super

    def foo(self, y, z):  # overridden function 
        ...  # Code we need to do before
        result = super().foo(y)
        ...  # Additional code after calling x.foo
        return new_result
```

Also check out https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super

Comment: Since this is practically the same information as Mister's answer above, I'd love some justification on why I got a downvote from him

Comment: I'm guessing because it applies more to what the user asked and it adds on to his example. While I understand what your example is demonstrating, I know if I would be a new user I would find it confusing and it wouldn't help me. Whereas his answer simplifies it and I can clearly see what is happening.

Comment: It needlessly uses an example separate from the OP‘s code. Most importantly, this example does not work - the super call of ˋ__init__ˋ passes unexpected parameters.

Comment: That's a fair point that it does deviate from what the user posted. I figured having a slightly different example would help them notice the difference between super.foo and super().foo. Though I can also see how it could be confusing since it does not run (begrudgingly accepting that missing that class x initalizer probably makes it worse)

Comment: Feel free to edit your answer and make it better. If you add the missing ˋx.__init__ˋ and use the chance to use PEP8 (i.e. camelcase class names), I feel it is very well suited to showing idiomatic use of ˋsuperˋ - the question code sadly is not named idiomatically, and being able to use ˋsuperˋ in ˋ__init__ˋ isn’t obvious to many beginners.